# apollo-server: Multiple Invocation of code on the Header

Tags: typescript, graphql, jwt, token, apollo-server

I am working on an Apollo Server implementation and encountering an issue where the code responsible for handling the authorization header and token is being executed multiple times, resulting in repeated console logs of the token and authorization header(The console log I place to find any issue). This behavior is unexpected and causes unnecessary processing.

Here are some relevant details:

- I am using Apollo Server, specifically the @apollo/server package, in my project.
- The server is set up with an ApolloServer instance and a context function to handle incoming requests.
- The context function retrieves the authorization header from the request and extracts the token for further processing.
- The issue manifests in the form of repeated console logs of the authorization header and token, even when I perform a single action.
- I suspect that there might be a misconfiguration or misunderstanding regarding the initialization or event handling in my Apollo Server setup, but I'm having trouble pinpointing the exact cause.

Code Snippet:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { GraphQLError } from 'graphql';
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import { MongoClient, ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import typeDefs from './graphql/typeDefs';
import resolvers from './graphql/resolvers';
import { formatError } from './graphql/formatErrors';
dotenv.config();

const PORT = Number.parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 8000;
interface MyContext {
    token?: String;
}

const startServer = async () => {
    try {
        const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI as string);
        await client.connect();
        console.log('MongoDB connection successful');

        const db = client.db();

        const server = new ApolloServer<MyContext>({
            schema: makeExecutableSchema({
                typeDefs,
                resolvers
            }),
            formatError,
            introspection: true
        });

        const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
            context: async ({ req }) => {
                const usersCollection = db.collection('users');
                const postsCollection = db.collection('posts');
                const authorizationHeader = req.headers.authorization || '';
                console.log(`authorizationHeader: ${authorizationHeader}`);
                const token = authorizationHeader.replace('Bearer ', '');
                console.log(`token: ${token}`);
                let user = null;
                let userId = null;

                if (token) {
                    try {
                        // Verify and decode the access token
                        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(
                            token,
                            process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY
                        ) as JwtPayload;
                        console.log(`decodedToken: ${decodedToken}`);
                        // Extract user information from the decoded token
                        const { user_id, email } = decodedToken;
                        userId = user_id;
                        user = await usersCollection.findOne({
                            _id: new ObjectId(user_id)
                        });
                        console.log(`user: ${user}`);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error decoding token:', error);
                    }
                }

                return { userId, user, usersCollection, postsCollection };
            },
            listen: { port: PORT }
        });
        console.log(`Server started at ${url}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to start the server:', error);
    }
};

startServer();
```

What I want?

For one click in the apollo documentation prints token and authorization like 6 or 7 times, there is posible to just print one, I mean avoid this repetetive proccess?

```
C:\Users\juanf\OneDrive\Escritorio\superproject2 [master ≡ +0 ~1 -0 !]> npm start

> example@1.0.0 start
> npm run build && ts-node src/server.ts


> example@1.0.0 build
> rimraf ./build && tsc

MongoDB connection successful
Server started at http://localhost:8000/
authorizationHeader:
token:
authorizationHeader:
token:
authorizationHeader:
token:
authorizationHeader:
token:
authorizationHeader:
token:
authorizationHeader:
token:
```